# After using absorb elements, will melee spell attacks grant the extra damage from absorb elements?

Tags: dnd-5e

After using absorb elements, will melee spell attacks grant the extra damage from absorb elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes any melee attack works.

> Also, the first time you hit with a **melee attack** on your next turn, the target takes an extra 1d6 damage of the triggering type, and the spell ends.
>
> [**emphasis** mine]

This does not distinguish between weapon attack, spell attack, or otherwise so a spell attack would trigger the effect.